# How can i change the scheduling of jobs dynamically using Spring/Quartz?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I'm launching/stopping the job(s) with these methods:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext scheduleContext;

public void startJobs() {
    scheduleContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
}

public void stopJobs() {
    scheduleContext.close();
}
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.2.xsd">

    <bean name="quartzJob"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobClass" value="mypackage.TestSpringJob" />
        <property name="durability" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="simpleTrigger"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="quartzJob" />
        <property name="repeatInterval" value="2000" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetails">
            <list>
                <ref bean="quartzJob" />
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="simpleTrigger" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Is it possible for example to change the `repeatInterval` property of a job or add new jobs to the scheduler dynamically?

If so, how can i achieve this?

Comment: I've been looking in StackOverflow but found no answer for your question. There are other questions related to change Quartz programatically but they do not seem to fit your problem. Maybe this helps https://darthanthony.wordpress.com/2009/07/07/dynamic-scheduling-with-javaspring/

Answer (score 1):

You can define the jobs and triggers dynamically and schedule the job dynamically.

```
    // Create Job
    JobDetailFactoryBean JobDetail = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
    jobDetail.setJobClass(ScheduledJob.class);
    jobDetail.setName("reportJob1");
    jobDetail.setDurability(true);
    jobDetail.setJobDataMap(new JobDataMap());
    jobDetail.afterPropertiesSet();

    // create CRON Trigger
    CronTriggerFactoryBean trigger = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
    trigger.setBeanName("UniqueCronBeanName");
    trigger.setGroup("uniqueCronGroup");
    trigger.setJobDetail(jobDetail.getObject());
    trigger.setCronExpression("0 0 12 * * ?");
    trigger.afterPropertiesSet();
```

Then you can schedule your job by setting it to defined scheduler Factory.

```
    schedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler().scheduleJob(jobDetail.getObject(), trigger.getObject());
```

To Update Scheduler repeat Interval or cron expression, It can be achieve as below.

```
    List<? extends Trigger> triggerList =
      schedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler().getTriggersOfJob(new JobKey(jobName, jobGroup));

    // get the trigger from Builder
    TriggerBuilder tb = triggerList.get(0).getTriggerBuilder();
    Trigger newTrigger =
         tb.withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withRepeatCount(10)).build();
    Date updatedTriggerDate =
     schedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler().rescheduleJob(triggerList.get(0).getKey(), newTrigger);
```

Comment: So, do you need to store `schedulerFactoryBean` in the memory? Or you just create a new one?

Comment: @NickDong I used this from org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean only. Autowired this for my purpose.